# Pandas: a Pythonic way to create a hyperlink from a value stored in another column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following toy dataset `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'id' : [1, 2, 3],
        'name' : ['John Smith', 'Sally Jones', 'William Lee']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    id  name
0   1   John Smith
1   2   Sally Jones
2   3   William Lee
```

My ultimate goal is to add a column that represents a Google search of the value in the `name` column.

I do this using:

```
def create_hyperlink(search_string):
    return f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search_string}'

df['google_search'] = df['name'].apply(create_hyperlink)
df

    id   name           google_search
0   1    John Smith     https://www.google.com/search?q=John Smith
1   2    Sally Jones    https://www.google.com/search?q=Sally Jones
2   3    William Lee    https://www.google.com/search?q=William Lee
```

Unfortunately, newly created `google_search` column is returning a malformed URL.  The URL should have a "+" between the first name and last name.

The `google_search` column should return the following:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=John+Smith
```

It's possible to do this using `split()` and `join()`.

```
foo = df['name'].str.split()
foo

0     [John, Smith]
1    [Sally, Jones]
2    [William, Lee]
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Now, joining them:

```
df['bar'] = ['+'.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['foo']]
df

    id  name    google_search   foo bar
0   1   John Smith  https://www.google.com/search?q=John Smith  [John, Smith]   John+Smith
1   2   Sally Jones https://www.google.com/search?q=Sally Jones [Sally, Jones]  Sally+Jones
2   3   William Lee https://www.google.com/search?q=William Lee [William, Lee]  William+Lee
```

Lastly, creating the updated `google_search` column:

```
df['google_search'] = df['bar'].apply(create_hyperlink)
df
```

Is there a more elegant, streamlined, *Pythonic* way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reinvent the wheel and modify your string manually, use a library that's guaranteed to give you the right result :

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus


def create_hyperlink(search_string):
    return f"https://www.google.com/search?q={quote_plus(search_string)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['google_search'] = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + \
    df.name.str.replace(' ','+')

print(df)

   id         name                                google_search
0   1   John Smith   https://www.google.com/search?q=John+Smith
1   2  Sally Jones  https://www.google.com/search?q=Sally+Jones
2   3  William Lee  https://www.google.com/search?q=William+Lee
```

Comment: This will only cover that particular case. It'd be better to use a more general url lib.

Comment: Yes, the `name` column in the production dataset includes some non-ascii characters (e.g. characters with accent marks).  `url lib` works perfectly.